# How do I create multilingual user path aliases?

Tags: i18n-l10n, path-aliases, 9

I'm setting up a multilingual site, and I need the user path aliases to be multilingual.

Users are set up as translatable:
[image: User Translation Configuration]

Language Detection: URL (path prefix)

- English: `/en`
- Japanese: No prefix

Pathauto patterns:

- English: `/en/users/[user:name]`
- Japanese: '`/users/[user:name]`

[image: Pathauto Patterns]

Example:

- Username: Admin

Expected paths:

- English: `/en/users/admin`
- Japanese: `/users/admin`

Actual:

- English: `/en/user/1`
- Main language: `/users/admin`

I've cleared the registry, regenerated the URLs, manually unset path aliases on the user then checked the box and re-saved, but I have not found any combination that results in multilingual path aliases.]

### Update

I've tried the following, which also did not work:

[image: Screenshot of alternate attempt]

Comment: Did you enable "URL detection mehtod" in Admin -> Configuration -> Regional and languages -> Languages -> Detection and selection? Aslo configuration translation and Content language translation module should be installed. Then you can set path auto patterns for each language. URLpattern will be www.youdomain.com/en/yourpattern. But the main language will also have the language code in the URL like /en /de /ru /fr - whatevery your base language is set to.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried your suggestions, but still no luck. I have updated the post with screenshots and additional information.

Comment: Have you tried with the the user original token like `users/[user:original:display-name]` and checking both the languages[en, jp] in one pattern config.

Comment: I just tried that (screenshot added to original post), and after deleting and regenerating all User aliases, still no luck. Thank you though.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Show the user detail page on the url users/{some_user} and /en/users/{some_user}? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I want to achieve what I outlined in the 'Expected' section of the post. For the path `/users/admin` the profile page of the Admin user is shown. for `/en/users/admin`, a 404 page is shown.

Comment: @Jaypan did you figure out sth more about this in the end?

Comment: Not yet, but there is a new post below I need to try. I will update after I have tried it.

Answer (score 1):

I followed your setup on a vanilla D9 and can report on the following:

- Pathauto aliases are created as expected
  [image]
  but only for translated users
  [image]
  That is an expected outcome looking at Pathauto's code, since it will start generating language specific aliases based on a pattern only for the translated languages of each entity during bulk updates and only for the active language of an entity during hook_entity_update.
- A manually created path alias
  [image]
  for an untranslated language of a user entity does work and resolves properly.
  [image]

In short, the answer is:

Multilingual user aliases are created automatically by Pathauto for each translated language of a user entity, or can be added manually for non-translated languages of a user entity.